# Unable to run Chrome in Selenium webdriver: Unspecified Path being displayed in error message

Tags: selenium, configuration, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I'm trying to launch selenium webdriver w chromedriver in Eclipse on a Mac and I'm running into a Configuration issue: "The driver executive does not exist" follow by a path. Now I know how to specify the path with using Set Property, but it is like a path already being populated there according to what I see in the error message. Even when I don't specify a path it still shows a path:

For example

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass beforeClass
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Users/ghols/Documents/workspace/selenium/null/chromedriver
```

BUT THIS IS MY CODE:

```
 @BeforeClass
  public void beforeClass()
{System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Users//gholms//Documents");

driver= new ChromeDriver();}
```

WHat is causing this issue? Why is a null path there that I never specified?? PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Add the `chromedriver.exe` name also to the end of the path as shown below.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Users//gholms//Documents//chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Users/gholms/Documents/workspace/selenium/Users/gholms/Documents/chrome/chromedriver.exe

Comment: Its like its an additional path always in there I changed the set property to:      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Users//gholms//Documents//chrome//chromedriver.exe");

Comment: Then, try to add `"Users//gholms//Documents//chrome//‌​chromedriver.exe"` to the CLASSPATH variable and also make sure the `chromedriver` file is present in the above mentioned path.

Comment: FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass beforeClass
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list
 at com.google.co

Comment: ITs like a path there already being displayed. I don't get it

Comment: now it gives a different message:java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable is a directory: /Applications/chrome

Comment: can you let me know the link from where you have downloaded the `chromedriver.exe` file?

Comment: In your MAC system is the chrome browser present at the following location?
`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`

Comment: Yes here is the path for Google chrome executable:/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS   Here is path for chromedriver executable:/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS    I put both executables here :-/